# rrdf and local triple stores in R

Tags: r, rdf, jena, tdb

I am using the **[rrdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrdf/index.html)** package to use RDF data in R.
The library seems really nice, but there is no information about the possibility of local triple stores, such as **[TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/java_api.html)**. Is it possible to use them, as they are part of Jena? Are there alternatives?

Thanks,

Mulone

Comment: Did you see [A short tutorial on rrdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrdf/vignettes/tutorial.pdf) by the author, in which he writes, "At this moment only in-memory stores are supported, though the code shared with Bioclipse was later been extended with on-disk stores, and I still need to port that code to
this package."  That's dated January 2014. The best bet might be join the mailing list and ask about it.  Fortunately, he also mentions that "[the] store is in fact a Java object form the Jena library," which means that the on-disk support might actually be a TDB based store.

Comment: Also note, though, that "The rrdf package allows you to query local and remote stores."  This means that you could set up a TDB store on disk, create an endpoint with Jena's Fuseki, and treat it as a "remote store".

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The store is in fact a Java object form the Jena library, which means that the on-disk support might actually be a TDB based store.
>
> You could set up a TDB store on disk, create an endpoint with Jena's Fuseki, and treat it as a "remote store".